# How do I change the name of the "view" node tab for a specific content type?

Tags: 8

I am using Drupal 8. I have a content type "hotel". I would like to change the default tab name "View" only for this content type "hotel". I can change the default tab name "View" by mymodule.links.task.yml (please see below code), but it applies to all content types.

```
entity.node.canonical:
  route_name: entity.node.canonical
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
  title: 'Summary'
```

So how do I change the default tab name "View" ONLY for a content type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your theme open file THEMENAME.theme, and the add code below:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_menu_local_task(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['element']['#link']['title']) && $variables['element']['#link']['title'] == 'View') {
    $node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
    if ($node && $node->getType() == 'hotel') {
      $variables['link']['#title'] = t('Hotel View');
    }
  }
}
```

Clear all cache and see result.